# How to programmatically navigate using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

With `react-router` I can use the `Link` element to create links which are natively handled by react router.

I see internally it calls `this.context.transitionTo(...)`.

I want to do a navigation. Not from a link, but from a dropdown selection (as an example). How can I do this in code? What is `this.context`?

I saw the `Navigation` mixin, but can I do this without `mixins`?

Answer (score 2554, accepted):

> UPDATE: 2022: **React Router v6.6.1 with useNavigate**

The `useHistory()` hook is now deprecated. If you are using React Router 6, the proper way to navigate programmatically is as follows:

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleClick() {
    navigate("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

> **React Router v5.1.0 with hooks**

There is a new `useHistory` hook in React Router >5.1.0 if you are using React >16.8.0 and functional components.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

> **React Router v4**

With v4 of React Router, there are three approaches that you can take to programmatic routing within components.

1. Use the `withRouter` higher-order component.
2. Use composition and render a `<Route>`
3. Use the `context`.

React Router is mostly a wrapper around the [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) library. `history` handles interaction with the browser's [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) for you with its browser and hash histories. It also provides a memory history which is useful for environments that don't have a global history. This is particularly useful in mobile app development (`react-native`) and unit testing with Node.

A `history` instance has two methods for navigating: `push` and `replace`. If you think of the `history` as an array of visited locations, `push` will add a new location to the array and `replace` will replace the current location in the array with the new one. Typically you will want to use the `push` method when you are navigating.

In earlier versions of React Router, you had to create your own `history` instance, but in v4 the `<BrowserRouter>`, `<HashRouter>`, and `<MemoryRouter>` components will create a browser, hash, and memory instances for you. React Router makes the properties and methods of the `history` instance associated with your router available through the context, under the `router` object.

#### 1. Use the `withRouter` higher-order component

The `withRouter` higher-order component will inject the `history` object as a prop of the component. This allows you to access the `push` and `replace` methods without having to deal with the `context`.

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
// this also works with react-router-native

const Button = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => { history.push('/new-location') }}
  >
    Click Me!
  </button>
))
```

#### 2. Use composition and render a `<Route>`

The `<Route>` component isn't just for matching locations. You can render a pathless route and **it will always match the current location**. The `<Route>` component passes the same props as `withRouter`, so you will be able to access the `history` methods through the `history` prop.

```js
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Button = () => (
  <Route render={({ history}) => (
    <button
      type='button'
      onClick={() => { history.push('/new-location') }}
    >
      Click Me!
    </button>
  )} />
)
```

#### 3. Use the context*

**But you probably should not**

The last option is one that you should only use if you feel comfortable working with React's [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) model (React's Context API is stable as of v16).

```js
const Button = (props, context) => (
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => {
      // context.history.push === history.push
      context.history.push('/new-location')
    }}
  >
    Click Me!
  </button>
)

// you need to specify the context type so that it
// is available within the component
Button.contextTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.shape({
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  })
}
```

1 and 2 are the simplest choices to implement, so for most use cases, they are your best bets.

Comment: I tried to use method 1 in this way  withRouter(( { history } ) => { console.log("hhhhhhhh"); history.push('/bets') }); But it never worked with router 4

Comment: WHAT!? I can just use `withRouter` instead of passing `history` down through all of my components?? Gahh I need to spend more time reading docs...

Comment: How can you just run `history.push('/new-location')` without attaching that behaviour to a Button or other DOM element?

Comment: `context` isn't experimental anymore as of react 16.

Comment: Update: for those who use eact-router-dom v6 should use useNavigate() instead of useHistory(). See the following answer for more detail.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66971821/12572265

Comment: Only a update. In v6 you need use useNavegate hook.

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('URL')

Comment: @Dmitry When using the history method, your ```<Route/>``` tags must all be wrapped inside the ```<Router></Router>``` tag. Make sure there aren't things like a MaterialUI CSS tag in the way messing up scope. (in the App.js file)

Comment: React Router v6 replaced `useHistory` with `useNavigate`, which is obviously a more delarative/appropriate name for the hook.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Comment: `withRouter` is deprecated as it breaks with memoization.

Answer (score 1424):

> **React-Router v6+** Answer

**TL;DR:** You can use the new `useNavigate` hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Component() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  // Somewhere in your code, e.g. inside a handler:
  navigate("/posts"); 
}
```

The `useNavigate` hook returns a function which can be used for programmatic navigation.

Example from the react router [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function SignupForm() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await submitForm(event.target);
    navigate("../success", { replace: true });
    // replace: true will replace the current entry in 
    // the history stack instead of adding a new one.

  }

  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* ... */}</form>;
}
```

> **React-Router 5.1.0+** Answer (using hooks and React >16.8)

You can use the `useHistory` hook on Functional Components and Programmatically navigate:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();
  // use history.push('/some/path') here
};
```

> **React-Router 4.0.0+** Answer

In 4.0 and above, use the history as a prop of your component.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
   // use `this.props.history.push('/some/path')` here
};
```

NOTE: `this.props.history` does not exist in the case your component was not rendered by `<Route>`. You should use `<Route path="..." component={YourComponent}/>` to have `this.props.history` in YourComponent

> **React-Router 3.0.0+** Answer

In 3.0 and above, use the router as a prop of your component.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
   // use `this.props.router.push('/some/path')` here
};
```

> **React-Router 2.4.0+** Answer

In 2.4 and above, use a higher order component to get the router as a prop of your component.

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Example extends React.Component {
   // use `this.props.router.push('/some/path')` here
};

// Export the decorated class
var DecoratedExample = withRouter(Example);

// PropTypes
Example.propTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.shape({
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};
```

> **React-Router 2.0.0+** Answer

This version is backwards compatible with 1.x so there's no need to an Upgrade Guide. Just going through the examples should be good enough.

That said, if you wish to switch to the new pattern, there's a `browserHistory` module inside the router that you can access with

`import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'`

Now you have access to your browser history, so you can do things like push, replace, etc... Like:

`browserHistory.push('/some/path')`

Further reading:
[Histories](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/Histories.md) and
[Navigation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

---

> **React-Router 1.x.x** Answer

I will not go into upgrading details. You can read about that in the [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md)

The main change about the question here is the change from `Navigation` mixin to `History`. Now it's using the browser historyAPI to change route so we will use `pushState()` from now on.

Here's an exemple using Mixin:

```js
var Example = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ History ],
  navigateToHelpPage () {
    this.history.pushState(null, `/help`);
  }
})
```

Note that this `History` comes from [rackt/history](https://github.com/rackt/history) project. Not from React-Router itself.

If you don't want to use Mixin for some reason (maybe because of ES6 class), then you can access the history that you get from the router from `this.props.history`. It will be only accessible for the components rendered by your `Router`. So, if you want to use it in any child components it needs to be passed down as an attribute via `props`.

You can read more about the new release at their [1.0.x documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/1.0.x/docs)

Here is [a help page specifically about navigating outside your component](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

It recommends grabbing a reference `history = createHistory()` and calling `replaceState` on that.

> **React-Router 0.13.x** Answer

I got into the same problem and could only find the solution with the Navigation mixin that comes with react-router.

Here's how I did it

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Navigation} from 'react-router';

let Authentication = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Navigation],

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.transitionTo('/');
  },

  render(){
    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</div>);
  }
});
```

I was able to call `transitionTo()` without the need to access `.context`

Or you could try the fancy ES6 `class`

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Authentication extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.context.router.transitionTo('/');
  }

  render(){
    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</div>);
  }
}

Authentication.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

> **React-Router-Redux**
>
> **Note:** if you're using Redux, there is another project called
> [React-Router-Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) that gives you
> redux bindings for ReactRouter, using somewhat the same approach that
> [React-Redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux) does

React-Router-Redux has a few methods available that allow for simple navigating from inside action creators. These can be particularly useful for people that have existing architecture in React Native, and they wish to utilize the same patterns in React Web with minimal boilerplate overhead.

Explore the following methods:

- `push(location)`
- `replace(location)`
- `go(number)`
- `goBack()`
- `goForward()`

Here is an example usage, with [Redux-Thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk):

**./actioncreators.js**

```js
import { goBack } from 'react-router-redux'

export const onBackPress = () => (dispatch) => dispatch(goBack())
```

**./viewcomponent.js**

```js
<button
  disabled={submitting}
  className="cancel_button"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onBackPress()
  }}
>
  CANCEL
</button>
```

Comment: I was hoping useNavigate was the solution, but version 6.2.1 it seems to be ignoring the `{ replace: true }` and doesn't refresh the page.

Comment: The [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) aren't clear about the purpose or expected behavior of including the second optional param `replace: state`.

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't use hooks?

Answer (score 553):

> **React-Router v2**

For the most recent release (`v2.0.0-rc5`), the recommended navigation method is by directly pushing onto the history singleton. You can see that in action in the [Navigating outside of Components doc](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md).

Relevant excerpt:

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/some/path');
```

If using the newer react-router API, you need to make use of the `history` from `this.props` when inside of components so:

```js
this.props.history.push('/some/path');
```

It also offers `pushState` but that is deprecated per logged warnings.

If using `react-router-redux`, it offers a `push` function you can dispatch like so:

```js
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
this.props.dispatch(push('/some/path'));
```

However this may be only used to change the URL, not to actually navigate to the page.

Comment: Don't forget that the newer API doesn't use `import { browserHistory } from './react-router'` but instead creates history using `import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'`. Later on, you can access `history` from the components props: `this.props.history('/some/path')`

Answer (score 90):

#### React-Router 4.x answer

On my end, I like to have a single history object that I can carry even outside components. I like to have a single history.js file that I import on demand, and just manipulate it.

You just have to change `BrowserRouter` to Router, and specify the history prop. This doesn't change anything for you, except that you have your own history object that you can manipulate as you want.

You need to install [history](https://github.com/reacttraining/history), the library used by `react-router`.

Example usage, [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) notation:

**history.js**

```js
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

**BasicComponent.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import history from './history';

class BasicComponent extends Component {

    goToIndex(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        history.push('/');
    }

    render(){
        return <a href="#" onClick={this.goToIndex}>Previous</a>;
    }
}
```

If you have to navigate from a component that is actually rendered from a `Route` component, you can also access history from props, like that:

**BasicComponent.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BasicComponent extends Component {

    navigate(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push('/url');
    }

    render(){
        return <a href="#" onClick={this.navigate}>Previous</a>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 86):

Here's how you do this with [`react-router v2.0.0`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md) with [ES6](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/). `react-router` has moved away from mixins.

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  navigateToPage = () => {
    this.context.router.push('/my-route')
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.navigateToPage}>Go!</button>
    );
  }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 77):

For this one, who does not control the server side and because of this is using hash router v2:

Place your [history](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1967) into separate file (e.g. app_history.js ES6):

```js
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false });

export default appHistory;
```

And use it everywhere!

Your entry point for react-router (app.js ES6):

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import appHistory from './app_history'
...
const render((
  <Router history={appHistory}>
  ...
  </Router>
), document.querySelector('[data-role="app"]'));
```

Your navigation inside any component (ES6):

```js
import appHistory from '../app_history'
...
ajaxLogin('/login', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); // login failed
  } else {
    // logged in
    appHistory.replace('/dashboard'); // or .push() if you don't need .replace()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 69):

#### React Router v6

I haven't touched React in a while, but want to thank and highlight [the comment below by *Shimrit Snapir*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router#comment114013988_47432985):

> `on React-Router 6.0 <Redirect /> changed to <Navigate />`

### React Router V4

tl:dr;

```js
if (navigate) {
  return <Redirect to="/" push={true} />
}
```

**The simple and declarative answer is that you need to use `<Redirect to={URL} push={boolean} />` in combination with `setState()`**

> **push: boolean -** when true, redirecting will push a new entry onto the history instead of replacing the current one.

---

```js
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

class FooBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    navigate: false
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.state

    // Here is the important part
    if (navigate) {
      return <Redirect to="/" push={true} />
    }
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ navigate: true })}>
          Home
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

A full example is [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). Read more [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).

*PS. The example uses [ES7+ Property Initializers](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers) to initialise state. Look [here](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus) as well, if you're interested.*

Answer (score 57):

> **Warning:** this answer covers only ReactRouter versions before 1.0
>
> I will update this answer with 1.0.0-rc1 use cases after!

You can do this without mixins too.

```js
let Authentication = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
  },
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.transitionTo('/');
  },
  render(){
    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</div>);
  }
});
```

The gotcha with contexts is that it is not accessible unless you define the `contextTypes` on the class.

As for what is context, it is an object, like props, that are passed down from parent to child, but it is passed down implicitly, without having to redeclare props each time. See https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html

Answer (score 50):

Here's the simplest and cleanest way to do it, circa current React-Router 3.0.0 and [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015):

> React-Router 3.x.x with ES6:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Example extends React.Component {
   // use `this.props.router.push('/some/path')` here
};

// Export the decorated class
export default withRouter(Example);
```

Or, if it's not your default class, export like:

```js
withRouter(Example);
export { Example };
```

Note that in 3.x.x, the `<Link>` component itself is using `router.push`, so you can pass it anything you would pass the `<Link to=` tag, like:

```
   this.props.router.push({pathname: '/some/path', query: {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'})'
```

Answer (score 42):

To do the navigation programmatically, you need to push a new **history** to the **props.history** in your `component`, so something like this can do the work for you:

```js
//using ES6
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    /* Look at here, you can add it here */
    this.props.history.push('/redirected');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Redirect!!!
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540162/unable-to-fetch-a-field-from-a-table-in-react/77540481?noredirect=1#comment136699940_77540481

Answer (score 41):

For ES6 + React components, the following solution worked for me.

I followed Felippe skinner, but added an end to end solution to help beginners like me.

Below are the versions I used:

> "react-router": "^2.7.0"
>
> "react": "^15.3.1"

Below is my react component where I used programmatic navigation using react-router:

```js
import React from 'react';

class loginComp extends React.Component {
   constructor( context) {
    super(context);
    this.state = {
      uname: '',
      pwd: ''
    };
  }

  redirectToMainPage(){
        this.context.router.replace('/home');
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
           // skipping html code 
             <button onClick={this.redirectToMainPage.bind(this)}>Redirect</button>
    </div>;
  }
};

 loginComp.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
 }

 module.exports = loginComp;
```

**Below is the configuration for my router:**

```js
 import { Router, Route, IndexRedirect, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

 render(<Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path='/' component={ParentComp}>
            <IndexRedirect to = "/login"/>
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginComp}/>
            <Route path='/home' component={HomeComp}/>
            <Route path='/repair' component={RepairJobComp} />
            <Route path='/service' component={ServiceJobComp} />
          </Route>
        </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 39):

It may not be the best approach but... Using react-router v4, the following TypeScript code could give an idea for some.

In the rendered component below, e.g. `LoginPage`, `router` object is accessible and just call `router.transitionTo('/homepage')` to navigate.

Navigation code was taken [from](https://react-router.now.sh/Match.).

`"react-router": "^4.0.0-2",`
`"react": "^15.3.1",`

```js
import Router from 'react-router/BrowserRouter';
import { History } from 'react-history/BrowserHistory';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();

interface MatchWithPropsInterface {
  component: typeof React.Component,
  router: Router,
  history: History,
  exactly?: any,
  pattern: string
}

class MatchWithProps extends React.Component<MatchWithPropsInterface,any> {
  render() {
    return(
      <Match {...this.props} render={(matchProps) => (
             React.createElement(this.props.component, this.props)

        )}
       />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      {({ router }) => (
        <div>
          <MatchWithProps exactly pattern="/" component={LoginPage} router={router} history={history} />
          <MatchWithProps pattern="/login" component={LoginPage} router={router} history={history} />
          <MatchWithProps pattern="/homepage" component={HomePage} router={router} history={history} />
          <Miss component={NotFoundView} />
        </div>
      )}
    </Router>,

   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 39):

In React Router v4, I follow these two ways to route programmatically.

1. `this.props.history.push("/something/something")`
2. `this.props.history.replace("/something/something")`

Number two

> Replaces the current entry on the history stack

To get history in props you may have to wrap your component with

> [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)

In React Router v6

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Invoices() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <NewInvoiceForm
        onSubmit={async event => {
          let newInvoice = await createInvoice(event.target);
          navigate(`/invoices/${newInvoice.id}`);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Getting Started with React Router v6](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/docs/installation/getting-started.md#navigating-programmatically)

Answer (score 29):

With React-Router v4 on the horizon, there is now a new way of doing this.

```
import { MemoryRouter, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router';

const navigator = global && global.navigator && global.navigator.userAgent;
const hasWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const isBrowser = typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.indexOf('Node.js') === -1;
const Router = isBrowser ? BrowserRouter : MemoryRouter;

<Router location="/page-to-go-to"/>
```

[react-lego](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego) is an example app that shows [how to use/update react-router](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/compare/react-router-4) and it includes example functional tests which navigate the app.

Comment: This is great for navigating from the render function, though I wonder how to navigate from something like a lifecycle hook, or redux?

Answer (score 29):

> In **React-Router v4** and **ES6**

You can use `withRouter` and `this.props.history.push`.

```js
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.history.push('/redirect-to');
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Answer (score 29):

To use `withRouter` with a class-based component, try something like this below.
Don't forget to change the export statement to use `withRouter`:

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

```
class YourClass extends React.Component {
  yourFunction = () => {
    doSomeAsyncAction(() =>
      this.props.history.push('/other_location')
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={ this.yourFunction } />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourClass);
```

Answer (score 26):

Based on the previous [answers from José Antonio Postigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/39769838#39769838) [and Ben Wheeler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/40890372#40890372):

The novelty? Is to be written in **TypeScript** and uses **decorators**
*or* a **static** property/field

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Component = React.Component;
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export interface INavigatorProps {
    router?: ReactRouter.History.History;
}

/**
 * Note: goes great with mobx
 * @inject("something") @withRouter @observer
 */
@withRouter
export class Navigator extends Component<INavigatorProps, {}>{
    navigate: (to: string) => void;
    constructor(props: INavigatorProps) {
        super(props);
        let self = this;
        this.navigate = (to) => self.props.router.push(to);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={() => this.navigate("/home")}>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li onClick={() => this.navigate("/about")}>
                    About
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Non decorated
 */
export class Navigator2 extends Component<INavigatorProps, {}> {

    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    navigate: (to: string) => void;
    constructor(props: INavigatorProps, context: any) {
        super(props, context);
        let s = this;
        this.navigate = (to) =>
            s.context.router.push(to);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={() => this.navigate("/home")}>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li onClick={() => this.navigate("/about")}>
                    About
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

with whatever npm installed today.

"react-router": "^3.0.0" and 
"@types/react-router": "^2.0.41"

Answer (score 23):

For those who are already using React Router v6, this can be done using `useNavigate` hook provided by `react-router`.

Navigation with this hook is pretty simple:

```
import { generatePath, useNavigate } from 'react-router';

navigate(-1); // navigates back
navigate('/my/path'); // navigates to a specific path
navigate(generatePath('my/path/:id', { id: 1 })); // navigates to a dynamic path, generatePath is very useful for url replacements
```

Answer (score 21):

For Latest **react-router-dom v6**

`useHistory()` is replaced with `useNavigate()`.

You need to use:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/your-page-link');
```

Answer (score 19):

React Router v6 with hooks

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
let navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('home');
```

And to move across the browser history,

```
navigate(-1); ---> Go back
navigate(1);  ---> Go forward
navigate(-2); ---> Move two steps backward.
```

Answer (score 17):

With the current React version (15.3), `this.props.history.push('/location');` worked for me, but it showed the following warning:

> browser.js:49 Warning: [react-router] `props.history` and
>   `context.history` are deprecated. Please use `context.router`.

and I solved it using `context.router` like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.backPressed = this.backPressed.bind(this);
    }

    backPressed() {
        this.context.router.push('/back-location');
    }

    ...
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using hash or browser history then you can do

```
hashHistory.push('/login');
browserHistory.push('/login');
```

Answer (score 14):

React-Router V4

If you're using version 4 then you can use my library (*shameless* plug) where you simply dispatch an action and everything just works!

```
dispatch(navigateTo("/aboutUs"));
```

[trippler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trippler)

Answer (score 13):

Those who are facing issues in implementing this in React Router v4.

Here is a working solution for navigating through the React app from redux actions.

#### File *history.js*

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createHistory()
```

#### Files *App.js/Route.jsx*

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'
...
<Router history={history}>
 <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
</Router>
```

#### File *another_file.js *or* redux file

```
import history from './history'

history.push('/test') // This should change the URL and rerender Test component
```

All thanks to this comment on GitHub:
[ReactTraining issues comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3498#issuecomment-301057248)

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook in a stateless component. Example from the documentation:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router"

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => history.push("/home")}>
      Go home
    </button>
  )
}
```

> Note: Hooks were added in [`react-router@5.1.0`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0) and require `react@>=16.8`

Comment: Good call, could you note which version of react-router and react that refers to? This is a new change that wasn't always available

Answer (score 10):

**Programmatically navigate in class-based components.**

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    state = {rpath: null}

    const goTo = (path) => this.setState({rpath: path});

    render(){
        if(this.state.rpath){
            return <Redirect to={this.state.rpath}/>
        }
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In my answer there are three different ways to redirect programmatically to a route. Some of the solutions has been presented already, but the following ones focused only for ***functional components*** with an additional demo application.

**Using the following versions:**

> react: **16.13.1**
>
> react-dom: **16.13.1**
>
> react-router: **5.2.0**
>
> react-router-dom: **5.2.0**
>
> typescript: **3.7.2**

**Configuration:**

So first of all the solution is using `HashRouter`, configured as follows:

```
<HashRouter>
    // ... buttons for redirect

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/(|home)" children={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/usehistory" children={UseHistoryResult} />
      <Route exact path="/withrouter" children={WithRouterResult} />
      <Route exact path="/redirectpush" children={RedirectPushResult} />
      <Route children={Home} />
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

From [the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) about `<HashRouter>`:

> A `<Router>` that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. `window.location.hash`) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

**Solutions:**

1. **Using `<Redirect>` to push using `useState`:**

Using in a functional component ([`RedirectPushAction`](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples/blob/master/src/RedirectPushAction/index.tsx) component from my repository) we can use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to handle redirect. The tricky part is once the redirection happened, we need to set the `redirect` state back to `false`. By using `setTimeOut` with `0` delay we are waiting until React commits `Redirect` to the DOM and then getting back the button in order to use it the next time.

Please find my example below:

```
const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
const handleRedirect = useCallback(() => {
    let render = null;
    if (redirect) {
        render = <Redirect to="/redirectpush" push={true} />

        // In order wait until committing to the DOM
        // and get back the button for clicking next time
        setTimeout(() => setRedirect(false), 0);
    }
    return render;
}, [redirect]);

return <>
    {handleRedirect()}
    <button onClick={() => setRedirect(true)}>
        Redirect push
    </button>
</>
```

From [`<Redirect>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) documentation:

> Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

2. **Using `useHistory` hook:**

In my solution there is a component called [`UseHistoryAction`](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples/blob/master/src/UseHistoryAction/index.tsx) which represents the following:

```
let history = useHistory();

return <button onClick={() => { history.push('/usehistory') }}>
    useHistory redirect
</button>
```

> The `useHistory` hook gives us access to the history object which helps us programmatically navigate or change routes.

3. **Using `withRouter`, get the `history` from `props`:**

Created one component called [`WithRouterAction`](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples/blob/master/src/WithRouterAction/index.tsx), displays as below:

```
const WithRouterAction = (props:any) => {
    const { history } = props;

    return <button onClick={() => { history.push('/withrouter') }}>
        withRouter redirect
    </button>
}

export default withRouter(WithRouterAction);
```

Reading from [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) documentation:

> You can get access to the `history` object's properties and the closest `<Route>`'s match via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter` will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

**Demo:**

For better representation I have built a GitHub repository with these examples, please find it below:

*[React Router Programmatically Redirect Examples](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples)*

Answer (score 8):

The right answer was for me at the time of writing

```js
this.context.router.history.push('/');
```

But you need to add PropTypes to your component

```js
Header.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
export default Header;
```

Don't forget to import PropTypes

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to pair RR4 with redux through [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux), using the routing action creators from `react-router-redux` is an option as well.

```
import { push, replace, ... } from 'react-router-redux'

class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
  handleRedirect(url, replaceState = true) {
    replaceState
      ? this.props.dispatch(replace(url))
      : this.props.dispatch(push(url))
  }
  render() { ... }
}

export default connect(null)(WrappedComponent)
```

If you use redux thunk/saga to manage async flow, import the above action creators in redux actions and hook to React components using mapDispatchToProps might be better.

Answer (score 8):

Try [React Hook Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hookrouter) instead, "the modern alternative to react-router":

```
import { useRoutes, usePath, A} from "hookrouter";
```

To answer the OP's question about linking through a select box, you can do it:

```
navigate('/about');
```

#### Updated answer

I think React Hook Router was a good starter kit and helped me learn about routing, but I have since updated to [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) for its history and query parameter handling.

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


const Component = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    // Programmatically navigate
    history.push(newUrlString);
}
```

You push where you want to navigate into the location.history.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe not the best solution, but it gets the job done:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// Create functional component Post
export default Post = () => (
    <div className="component post">

        <button className="button delete-post" onClick={() => {
            // ... delete post
            // then redirect, without page reload, by triggering a hidden Link
            document.querySelector('.trigger.go-home').click();
        }}>Delete Post</button>

        <Link to="/" className="trigger go-home hidden"></Link>

    </div>
);
```

Basically, logic tied to one action (in this case a post deletion) will end up calling a trigger for redirect. This is not ideal, because you will add a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) node 'trigger' to your markup just so you can conveniently call it when needed. Also, you will directly interact with the DOM, which in a React component may not be desired.

Still, this type of redirect is not required that often. So one or two extra, hidden links in your component markup would not hurt that much, especially if you give them meaningful names.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, and special imports were not needed:

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  name="back" 
  id="back" 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  value="Back" 
  onClick={() => { this.props.history.goBack() }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use `useNavigate` for simplicity with the latest version of react

***Newfile.js***

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Newfile = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
   
    ....

    navigate("yourdesiredlocation");

    ....
}

export default Newfile;
```

Use `useNavigate` feature like above in your code.

Answer (score 5):

#### For React Router v4+

Assuming that you won't be needing to navigate during the initial render itself (for which you can use `<Redirect>` component), this is what we are doing in our application.

Define an empty route which returns null. This will allow you to get the access to the history object. You need to do this at the top level where your `Router` is defined.

Now you can do all the things that can be done on [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history), like `history.push()`, `history.replace()`, `history.go(-1)`, etc.!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

let routeHistory = null;

export function navigateTo(path) {
  if(routeHistory !== null) {
    routeHistory.push(path);
  }
}

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <HashRouter hashType="noslash">
      <Route
        render={({ history }) => {
          routeHistory = history;
          return null;
        }}
      />
      {/* Rest of the App */}
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**react-router-dom: 5.1.2**

- This site has 3 pages, all of which are rendered  dynamically in the browser.
- Although the page does not ever refresh, notice how  React Router
  keeps the URL up to date as you navigate  through the site. This
  preserves the browser history,  making sure things like the back
  button and bookmarks work properly
- *A **Switch** looks through all its children 
        elements and renders the first one whose path
        matches the current URL. Use a  any time
        you have multiple routes, but you want only one
        of them to render at a time*

````
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";



export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

// You can think of these components as "pages"
// in your app.

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question with so many answers, try to show the benefits of yours.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question which is how to do it programmatically from imperative js, not with markup.

Answer (score 4):

Using the "useHistory" hook is the best option if you're using a newer version of React.

Answer (score 4):

This is already mentioned that we can navigate in the last update React Router V6 (doesn't include `useHistory`) using `useNavigate()`

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const myComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate('my_url');
  ...
}
```

But what I could not find here is calling navigate out of React component like navigating page inside `redux-saga` function to another page. Just in case, if you have the same question, here is what I found.

In your root component (I call that `<App />`)

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import useBus from 'use-bus';

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useBus('@@ui/navigate', (action) => navigate(action.payload.url), []);
  ...
}
```

Out of React component (in my case `redux-saga` function)

```js
import { dispatch } from 'use-bus';

dispatch({ type: '@@ui/navigate', payload: { url: '/404' } });
```

Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Those are couple of ways you can use for this case, I hope you benifit from them.

There are a few ways to do programmatic routing in React.js using React Router without using the `Link` component.

**1. Use the `useNavigate` hook.**

The `useNavigate` hook allows you to navigate to a different route programmatically. To use it, you first need to import it from React Router:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then, you can call the `useNavigate` hook inside of your component to get a function that you can use to navigate to a different route:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

To navigate to a different route, simply call the `navigate` function with the path of the route that you want to navigate to:

```js
navigate('/new-page');
```

You can also pass additional options to the `navigate` function, such as the state of the route and whether or not to replace the current history entry:

```js
navigate('/new-page', {
  state: {
    message: 'Hello from the new page!',
  },
  replace: true,
});
```

**2. Use the `history` object.**

The `history` object is a global object that allows you to manipulate the browser's history stack. You can use it to navigate to a different route, go back or forward in history, and more.

To access the `history` object, you can use the `useHistory` hook from React Router:

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then, you can call the `push()`, `replace()`, and `goBack()` methods on the `history` object to navigate to different routes:

```js
history.push('/new-page');
```

```js
history.replace('/new-page');
```

```js
history.goBack();
```

**3. Use the `<Navigate>` component.**

The `<Navigate>` component is a new component in React Router v6 that allows you to navigate to a different route programmatically. To use it, you first need to import it from React Router:

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then, you can use the `<Navigate>` component in your component like this:

```js
<Navigate to='/new-page' />
```

This will navigate to the `/new-page` route immediately.

Which method you choose to use for programmatic routing will depend on your specific needs and preferences. However, all of these methods are valid and can be used to navigate to different routes programmatically without using the `Link` component.

Here is an example of how to use the `useNavigate` hook to programmatically navigate to a different route when a button is clicked:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Button = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate('/new-page');
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Navigate to new page
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

This will navigate to the `/new-page` route when the button is clicked.

I hope this helps!

Comment: why the `const navigate = useNavigate();`  Seems to me it should just be UseNavigate('/new-page').

Answer (score 2):

You can try the onClick event in React and call a function to redirect to the specified location using useNavigate hook of React Router. You can directly use callback function in the onClick handler rather than specifying a different function. You first need to install react router DOM.

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

Try the below code

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Page = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => navigate('/pagename')}>
      Go To Page
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `useNavigate` from react router dom

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const MYComponent = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    navigate("Xyz/MYRoutes");

 
}

export default MYComponent;
```

Use `useNavigate` feature like above in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can tackle the option you want to let it do this thing.

```
<select>
 <option onClick={() => <Navigate to="/home" />}> Option 1 </option>
</select>
```

This  you'll find in react-router-dom
also you can use the hook, useNavigation()

const navigate = useNavigation();

```
navigate("/home") // use it onClick or anywhere.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   import react from "react";

    // importing navigate from react-router-dom
    import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
    
    function testNavigation() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    return (
    <>
    <button onClick={navigate("/")}> Test Navigate </button>

    </>
    )
    }
```

**please note:
before use nagivate path "/" in onClick make sure you already initial this path to your app.jsx file in your project which is provided react-router-dom in route.**

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! It would be very helpful if you could provide a brief explanation of the code you've posted and how it addresses the problem described in the question. This will make your answer more valuable for others who might come across this thread in the future, and will also help the original poster and other readers to understand the solution more clearly. Thanks in advance! If you need further knowledge check out: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just using the browser api, independent of any library

```
const navigate = (to) => {
    window.history.pushState({}, ",", to);
  };
```

this does not cause full page refresh. you can still use the browser back button

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to navigate programmatically:

1. Use web `history` API [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API] eg: `history("/route")`
2. Use callback function
3. use `push` from connected-react-router eg: `push({ pathname: "/route"})`

Answer (score 0):

In React Router, you can programmatically navigate to a different route using the useHistory hook (for functional components) or the withRouter HOC (for class components). Here's how you can do it using the useHistory hook:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    // Navigate to a different route programmatically
    history.push('/new-route');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to New Route</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

There are already a ***ton*** of answers which answer this question appropriately and accurately in the context of react router, but I'd like to take a moment to point out something that I didn't see mentioned in the other answers.

Kind of a stackoverflow trope to recommend doing something a different way than the original question asks, however in this case due to the age of the question I feel like the question would be stated differently in current time.

I'd recommend ditching react-router all together and just pushing to the native browser location, via `window.location.href = [your url here]`, and checking path via regex (or exact) matching window.location.pathname against your intended path.

The simpler answer is usually the best one, and in this case, the use case for React Router is better served by the native Location object API.

Comment: Your answer is good enough but breaks the best practices when using the ReactJs library - You don't want to manipulate DOM directly for many reasons.

Answer (score -1):

To perform navigation in React Router without using mixins, you can use the `useHistory` hook or the `withRouter` higher-order component (HOC). The `this.context` approach you mentioned is deprecated in React Router v6, so I'll provide examples using React Router v6.

1. Using the useHistory hook:
   The `useHistory` hook allows you to access the `history` object, which provides navigation functionalities. Here's an example of how you can navigate programmatically using a dropdown selection:

   ```
   import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

   function Dropdown() {
     const history = useHistory();

     const handleSelection = (path) => {
       history.push(path); // Navigate to the specified path
     };

     return (
       <select onChange={(e) => handleSelection(e.target.value)}>
         <option value="/">Home</option>
         <option value="/about">About</option>
         <option value="/contact">Contact</option>
       </select>
     );
   }
   ```

   In this example, the `useHistory` hook is imported from `react-router-dom`. Inside the `Dropdown` functional component, we access the `history` object via the `useHistory` hook.

   The `handleSelection` function is called whenever the dropdown selection changes. It uses `history.push()` to navigate to the specified path.
2. Using withRouter HOC:
   If you prefer using classes or a functional component without hooks, you can use the `withRouter` higher-order component to inject the `history` object as a prop. Here's an example:

   ```
   import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

   class Dropdown extends React.Component {
     handleSelection = (path) => {
       const { history } = this.props;
       history.push(path); // Navigate to the specified path
     };

     render() {
       return (
         <select onChange={(e) => this.handleSelection(e.target.value)}>
           <option value="/">Home</option>
           <option value="/about">About</option>
           <option value="/contact">Contact</option>
         </select>
       );
     }
   }

   export default withRouter(Dropdown);
   ```

   In this example, the `withRouter` HOC wraps the `Dropdown` component, injecting the `history` object as a prop. The `handleSelection` method uses `this.props.history.push()` to navigate to the specified path.

By using either the `useHistory` hook or the `withRouter` HOC, you can perform navigation programmatically in React Router without relying on mixins. Choose the method that best fits your project's requirements and coding style.

Answer (score -2):

layouts/BaseLayout.jsx

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

const BaseLayout = () => {
    return(
        <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <Outlet/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BaseLayout
```

routers/index.jsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import BaseLayout from "../layouts/BaseLayout";
import HomePage from "../views/HomePage";
import Menu from "../components/Menu"
import Detail from "../components/Detail";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <BaseLayout/>,
        children:[
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <Menu />,
            },
            {
                path: '/:id',
                element: <Detail/>
            }
        ]

    },
])

export default router
```

stores/actionType.js

```
export const FETCH_DATA_FOODS = "food/setFood"

export const FETCH_DATA_FOODS_DETAILS = "food/setDetailFood"
```

stores/reducers/reducer.js

```
import { FETCH_DATA_FOODS, FETCH_DATA_FOODS_DETAILS } from "../actionType";

const initialState = {
    foods:[],
    detailFood:{}
};

const foodReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_DATA_FOODS:
            return{
                ...state,
                foods: action.payload
            }
        case FETCH_DATA_FOODS_DETAILS:
            return{
                ...state,
                detailFood: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default foodReducer
```

stores/actionCreator

```
import { FETCH_DATA_FOODS, FETCH_DATA_FOODS_DETAILS } from "./actionType";

// import { FETCH_DATA_FOODS } from "../actionType";
export const actionFoodSetFoods = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA_FOODS,
    payload,
  };
};

export const actionDetailSetDetailFood = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA_FOODS_DETAILS,
    payload,
  };
};

export const fetchDataFoods = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    fetch("https://maxxkafe.foxhub.space/users")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("notOk");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // dispatcher({
        //     type: "food/setFood",
        //     payload: data
        // })

        dispatch(actionFoodSetFoods(data));
      });
  };
};

export const fetchDetailDataFood = (id) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log(id);
    fetch(`https://maxxkafe.foxhub.space/users/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("gaOkNich");
        }
        console.log(response, ",,,,,,,,");
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch(actionDetailSetDetailFood(data));
      });
  };
};
```

stores/index.js

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import foodReducer from './reducers/foodReducer'
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    foods: foodReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store
```

app.js

```
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "./routers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./stores";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

components/category.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchDataCategories } from "../stores/actionCreate";
import RowCategory from "../views/rowTableCategory";

const Category = () => {
  // const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
  const { categories } = useSelector((state) => state.categories);
  const dispatcher = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch("http://localhost:3003/categories")
    // .then((response) => {
    //     if(!response.ok){
    //         throw new Error ("gaOkNich")
    //     }
    //     return response.json()
    // })
    // .then((data) => {
    //     setCategories(data)
    // })
    dispatcher(fetchDataCategories());
  }, []);
  return (
    <section className="mt-12">
      <div className="flex mr-20 mb-4">
        <Link to={'/add-Form'} className="flex ml-auto text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 rounded">
          Create Category
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="overflow-hidden rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md m-5">
        <table className="w-full border-collapse bg-white text-left text-sm text-gray-500">
          <thead className="bg-gray-50">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900">
                Name
              </th>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900">
                Created At
              </th>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900">
                Updated At
              </th>
              <th
                scope="col"
                className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900"
              ></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-100 border-t border-gray-100">
            {categories.map((el) => {
              return <RowCategory key={el.id} el={el} />;
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

components/login.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchDataFoods, login } from "../stores/actionCreate";

const Login = () => {
  const input = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(input);
  // const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  // const {admin} = useSelector((state) => state.admin)

  const dispatcher = useDispatch();
  const movePage = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
    console.log(value);
  };

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      await dispatcher(login(values));
      await dispatcher(fetchDataFoods());
      movePage("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="font-mono bg-white-400 mt-[10rem]">
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="flex justify-center px-6 my-12">
          <div className="w-full xl:w-3/4 lg:w-11/12 flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-full lg:w-7/12 bg-white p-5 rounded-lg lg:rounded-l-none">
              <h3 className="pt-4 text-2xl text-center">Login Your Account!</h3>
              <form
                className="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 bg-white rounded"
                onSubmit={handleLogin}
              >
                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label
                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700"
                    htmlFor="email"
                  >
                    Email
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                    id="email"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    // onChange={(event) => setValues({email: event.target.value})}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.email.email}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-4 md:flex md:justify-between">
                  <div className="mb-4 md:mr-2 md:mb-0">
                    <label
                      className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700"
                      htmlFor="password"
                    >
                      Password
                    </label>
                    <input
                      className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border  rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                      id="password"
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      value={values.password}
                      // onChange={(event) => setValues({password: event.target.value})}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-4 md:flex md:justify-between"></div>
                <div className="mb-6 text-center">
                  <button
                    className="w-full px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Login
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

Comment: a lot of code not related to the answer to the question... you could at least comment what you're trying to demonstrate here

Answer (score -5):

Simply just use :

```js
this.props.history.push('/where/to/go');
```

Comment: This answer is not clear and useful. I think everything have been answered above clearly and explained in every version of React and React Router. Please add more information if you  think your answer is useful and better than them. 
Best regards
Arash Yazdani